# Comparar valor de array con parámetro de mi función con la instruccion for en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Como podría comparar los valores de mi arreglo con el parámetro de mi función usando `for`, por ejemplo que al ingresar una letra esta compare si es una vocal y si es `true` que diga es vocal, sino no es vocal.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

```js
const arreglo = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

function comparar(vocal) {
  for (i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i] == vocal) {
      return "Es vocal";
    } else {
      return "No es vocal";
    }
  }
}

console.log(comparar("e"))
```

Comment: Para qué usar un ciclo `for` si exiten métodos más eficientes como `find()` o `some()`?

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu código es que realizas un `return` prematuro. O dicho de otra manera, tu `for` solo ejecuta una sola iteración, ya que dentro tu `if/else` haces un `return` para cualquier caso, esto hace que retorne `es vocal` cuando la entrada es `a` y para cualquier otro caso retornará `No es vocal` y termina la iteración.

La solución es que retornes `es vocal` dentro del `for` y `No es vocal` fuera del `for`

```js
const arreglo = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

function comparar(vocal) {
  for (i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i] == vocal) {
      return "Es vocal";
    }
  }
 //no se encontró ninguna vocal, luego de haber recorrido todo el "arreglo", asi que "No es vocal"  
 return "No es vocal";
}

console.log(comparar("a"))
console.log(comparar("e"))
console.log(comparar("i"))
console.log(comparar("o"))
console.log(comparar("u"))
console.log(comparar("b"))
console.log(comparar("c"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que yo haria en tu caso es declarar una variable `isVowel` en `false`, al inicio de la funcion.

Luego utilizo el `for` para recorrer todo el array y convertir `isVowel` en `true` en el momento que encuentre la vocal. Si la encuentro uso un `break` para salir del `for`.

Al finalizar la iteracion por todo el array devuelvo el string `"Es vocal"` si `isVowel` es `true`, o `"No es vocal"` si `isVowel` es `false`.

```js
const arreglo=["a","e","i","o","u"]

function comparar(vocal){
    let isVowel = false;

    for(let i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
      if(arreglo[i] == vocal){
         isVowel = true;
         break;
      }
    }
        
    return isVowel ? "Es vocal" : "No es vocal";
}

console.log(comparar("r"))
```